Anime about a few families that have something called the dragon stones that gave them powers
I watched this anime when I was a kid. It used to be about 5 or 6 families that had a stone-something, called the dragon stones, that gave them certain powers or attributes.
The hero was from a family that used to have all the attributes and were handed down to the hero, not from his father but from his grandfather. He has two of those stones and the other families want those two, so they try to get them from the hero and they keep fighting.

In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was this a movie or a series?
